# Form post only a part of the model in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Models

```
public class ChildModel
{
    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
}

public class ParentModel
{
    public ChildModel Child { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <p>@Model.Child.Item1</p>
        <p>@Model.Child.Item2</p>
        <form asp-controller="home" asp-action="submit" method="post">
            <input asp-for="Child.Item1" hidden />
            <input asp-for="Child.Item2" hidden />
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark mr-2 px-4">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new ParentModel
    {
        Child = new ChildModel
        {
            Item1 = "Item 1",
            Item2 = "Item 2",
        }
    });
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Submit(ChildModel m)
{
    //ModelState.IsValid is true, but m.Item1 is null and m.Item2 is null
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(m);

    return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

What I am trying to do is post back only a member of my model. My assumption was that MVC model binding will pick up the `Item1` and `Item2` members from *form* data and I will be able to access them in my `Submit` post back. But in the `Submit` method, both `Item1` and `Item2` are always null.

Please can you suggest what am I doing wrong or may be some other method to achieve the same effect?

Comment: No! That question is not related to posting back model member (which is what the issue is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are modifying the model structure, you need to change the names of the inputs:

```
<input asp-for="Child.Item1" name="Item1" hidden />
<input asp-for="Child.Item2" name="Item2" hidden />
```

Otherwise, the HMTL generated would look like `... name="Child.Item1"...` and since your model doesn't have a `Child` property, as you see, it fails.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused by the phrase [It uses reflection and recursion to traverse the properties of complex types looking for matches.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) May be it will work If I had a `GrandParent` model but not with `Child` (Hope you see what I mean). :)